# Warning unused variable using typeid

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

I have written a small wrapper for `typeinfo` to get the typecode of a variable at compile time more easily:

```
template<typename DataType>
class TypeInfo
{
public:
    static const char* typecode()
    {
        DataType TypedVariable = 0;
        const char* code = typeid(TypedVariable).name(); 
        return(code);
    };
};
```

I use it like this:

`const char* code = TypeInfo<float>::typecode();`

It compiles perfectly fine and works as expected, but I am getting the warning

```
src/common.hh(153): warning: variable "TypedVariable" was set but never used
          detected during:
            instantiation of "char TypeInfo<DataType>::typecode() [with DataType=r32]"
...
```

I am wondering why "calling" `typeid()` on a variable does not count as using it.  I know that it is a defined keyword, but still I am irritated that getting the type of a variable does not count as using it.
The compilation is done using `nvcc` of CUDA 9.2. Maybe it is a CUDA specific thing?

Thanks for any help :)

//edit:
I made a mistake by not returning the full char* because I use only normal types! Thanks for making me aware of the typo! I also added the template definition. I forgot to copy that over!

Comment: You can just use `typeid(DataType)` and get rid of `TypedVariable` altogether.

Comment: Since `TypeInfo` has no state, why isn't `typecode()` a free function? You are aware that `typeid(foo).name()` ususally not only consists of one character?

Comment: Note that this function just returns the first letter of the `typeid`'s name. This seems very unusual to me. Are you sure this is what you meant to do?

Comment: @J.Doe from the error message, `TypeInfo` is clearly a template.

Comment: @MartinBonner Oh, thanks, i must have overread that. Changed my comment.

Comment: For non-polymorphic types, `typeid()` is evaluated at compile time.   Given `typeid(variable)` the compiler only needs to work out the type of `variable`.   This doesn't generally involve using that variable (e.g. setting or reading its value).     In any event, using `typeid(DataType)` will give the same effect without introducing a named variable.   As will  `typeid(DataType(0))`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I used a static function because I wanted to do something like numeric_limits, and there the definition is static. Additionally that allows me to call the function without having to instantiate an object

Comment: @Peter I have tried your suggestion with taking away the variable and I get an undefined symbol error: ```In function `TypeInfo<float>::typecode()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN8TypeInfoIfE8typecodeEv[_ZN8TypeInfoIfE8typecodeEv]+0x9): undefined reference to `typeinfo for float'```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't use the *value* of `TypedVariable`.  You just use its type (and you can get it's type by rewriting your initialization as:

```
        char const * const code = typeid(DataType).name();
```

Comment: ```#include <typeinfo>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char const * const code = typeid(float).name();
    printf("%s\n", code);
    return 0;
}```
does not compile...

Comment: @meetaig - it works for me: https://godbolt.org/z/Athzbr.  What is your error message?

Comment: ```$gcc main.cpp -o main.out
/tmp/ccjzm36x.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for float'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status```
i am using gcc 4.9.3

Comment: @meetaig You need `g++ main.cpp` - the difference between gcc and g++ is that the latter links in the C++ runtime library ... including the typeinfo objects for builtin types.  (I'm using gcc 4.8.4)